# Windows Server Domain User and Workstation Software

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, domain-controller, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a new server with windows server 2012(domain) and want to add a few new users and workstations( with AD), so all user could login on all workstations. That is easy, but now I would like to add a few software like office, pdf reader, video player etc. so that all users could use them on all workstation (on all the same). How could I do that?

Should I install all the software on all workstation or is there any other solutions. I ask because I would like to update (if any software need a update) the software on all workstations at the same time so I does not need to update each workstation separately, so all workstation get the update.

Whats the best solution. If you have any question please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I get it now how to do it.

I have to use the GPO (Group Policy object)! That helps to deploy the software on all workstations so I don't have to install it on all the workstation seperately :)